# vba quit word application very slow

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am running some vba code that takes data from access and fills in bookmarks in word using vba.  When i run wdapp.quit to close word app after saving the file and closing the file it takes about 2 to 3 mins to close the word app. If I comment out the line it runs really fast.

Comment: What's your closing command - can you monitor word if you turn the app visible?

Comment: There can be many reasons for this. Try isolating the problem, e.g. by removing the code that fills the bookmarks, or analyzing closing of Word without automation. Always a good candidate of course: Process Monitor with a filter on winword.exe.

Comment: i ran process monitor when running the code it ran closedthe file just but when trying to quit the word app it froze with no spike in cpu usage.  I have a msgbox saying complete and it runs but the sub is tied up for additional 2 mins after the box appears.

Comment: Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   
    Set wddoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(FINALFILE)
   
    
    
    For Each fld In rsword.Fields
   
        With fld
           
            ''Get the range of the bookmark
            bk_name = .Name
            Set rngBookmark = wddoc.BookMarks(bk_name).Range
           
          
                rngBookmark.Text = .Value 
        End With
   
    Next fld
   
    wddoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=FINALFILE, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    wddoc.Close
 
 
wdApp.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code. I had the same issue. It was super slow and each iteration took minutes just for closing the document. I was opening Word Documents in a loop, one by one, creating new objects from Word.Application and Word.Document and "destroying" them after usage INSIDE the loop. 

That's the mistake: After pulling Word.Application-handling out of the loop it runs like a charm and super-fast.

Answer (score 0):

By using SAVE instead of SAVEAS, and then filecopy of the saved document to the required folder, and deleting the saved doc, things speeded up.